# Tensorflow: Feeding every LSTM timestep into the same logit layer (generaly feeding a dynamic amount of tensors into one layer)

Tags: dynamic, tensorflow, reshape, lstm

I stumbled upon this issue while trying to build an LSTM-classifier. Using `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` to auto-unfold over time i get an output `lstm_output` of size `[batch_size, time_steps, number_cells]` from the lstm cell (ignoring the state which is also an output). Now this output should **for every timestep** be fed into the same fully connected layer (planned to use 
`tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(lstm_output_oneTimestep, numClasses)` to reduce the size from `number_cells` to `number_classes` (for using softmax). Now if i would know the amount of timesteps i could of course just write `time_steps` single nodes for my graph, which all use the same weights, but this is of course not only ridiculous, but also impossible for an **dynamic amount of timesteps** in the lstm. 
My question now is twofold: 
First i remember there was a way to **build an dynamic amount of similar nodes** in tensorflow quite easily, but i wasn't able to find it despite excessive googling stackoverflow (i'm aware this sounds ridiculous, i suppose i just try the wrong key words).
Second there must be a smarter way? I assume i could just reshape the output of the lstm to shape `[batch_size * max_time, number_cells]` and input it into a layer with weights of shape `[number_cells, number_classes]` to obtain something of shape `[batch_size * max_time, numberClasses]`? If this would work, is there a smart way to write this sort of reshaping in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

(Despite trying it for an hour before, just after asking you find some answers): 
If subquestion proposal from subquesiton two works, the reshaping can of course be done by tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.unstack(`lstm_output`)). Mea culpa. Still most of the question stands.

Comment: The reshaping strategy is how I do it.