# Feeding outputs from tensorflow dynamic_rnn to subsequent layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've started using RNNs in tensorflow and I get the general principle, but some aspects of the implementation aren't quite clear.

What I understand: Let's say I'm training a sequence-to-sequence network where the input is the same size as the output (which could be something like predicting the next character in a piece of text at every timestep). My recurrent layer uses an LSTM cell and I want a fully-connected layer afterward to add some more depth to the prediction.

In a static RNN, by TF convention you're supposed to unstack your input data across the time dimension and feed it to the `static_rnn` method as a list, like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

num_input_features = 32
num_output_features = 32

lstm_size = 128
max_seq_len = 5

# input/output:
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_seq_len, num_input_features])

x_series = tf.unstack(x, axis=1) # a list of length max_seq_len

# recurrent layer:
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x_series, dtype=tf.float32)
```

This gives you a list of outputs, one for each timestep. Then if you want to do some additional computation on the outputs of the RNN at every step, you can just do so to every element of the output list:

```
# output layer:

w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([lstm_size, num_output_features]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_output_features]))

z_series = [tf.matmul(out, w) + b for out in rnn_outputs]
yhat_series = [tf.nn.tanh(z) for z in z_series]
```

And then I can stack up `yhat_series` again and compare it to some labels `y` for my cost function.

Here's what I don't get: In a dynamic RNN, the input you feed to the `dynamic_rnn` method is instead a tensor with its own time dimension (axis 1 by default):

```
# input/output:
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_seq_len, num_input_features])

# x_series = tf.unstack(x, axis=1) # dynamic RNN does not need this

# recurrent layer:
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
dyn_rnn_outputs, dyn_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then `dyn_rnn_output` is not a list, but a tensor of shape (?, max_seq_len, lstm_size). What's the best way to handle feeding this tensor to a subsequent dense layer? I can't multiply the RNN outputs by my weight matrix, and unstacking the RNN outputs feels like an awkward hack that the dynamic_rnn API was designed to avoid.

Is there a good approach to this that I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330176/what-is-the-output-of-a-tf-nn-dynamic-rnn. It may make the output clearer for you. It depends on whether you only care about the final state or not.

Comment: I've found someone from 7 months ago asking what I think is the same question as I am asking here - but that one has no accepted answers either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433494/tensorflow-feeding-every-lstm-timestep-into-the-same-logit-layer-generaly-feed?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for anyone trying to figure this out:

There is a tensorflow function, `tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper`, that seems to be specifically for attaching a dense layer to the output of an RNN cell, but wraps it up as part of the RNN cell itself that you can then unroll with a call to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`:

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
proj = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(lstm_cell, num_output_features)
dyn_rnn_outputs, dyn_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(proj, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

But more generally, if you want to operate on the outputs of the RNN, the usual practice seems to be to reshape the `rnn_outputs` by unrolling across the batch and time dimensions, performing your operations on that tensor, and rolling them back up for the final output.